Toggle CSS onmouseover - Wordpress Menu
I have a wordpress menu in which every links a custom class.
Onmouseover, I'd like this class to change the css of another element in the page.
I tried without success:
$('.menuclass').onmouseover(function () {$('.other-element').toggleClass("hover");});

I might go the wrong way about it, do you guys have any idea?

onmouseover is not a valid jQuery method. Instead, you should use the hover() method or the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.
